# iOS Mail app displays blank mail body

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, email

In my Ruby on Rails application, the emails sent by Mailer display correctly on almost every device both for web browsers and email clients. However, for iOS Mail app on both iPhone and iPad, the email can be received successfully and mail title/preview shows correctly; Only the mail body part leaves a blank with nothing in it.

The tricky part is, I can still reply or forward this mail with the quoted original mail body appealing perfectly. It seems the exact problem here is that my mail body displays like a 'transparent' content.

So anyone has dealt with or has any clue on this matter?

The screenshot on iPhone is below: 
[image]

Comment: Can you post a (raw) sample with this problem?

Comment: @EdCottrell Screenshot added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by removing an external style sheet file for mail template.